# JSON parsing using NSJSONSerialization in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, nsjsonserialization

I am parsing a `JSON` in my code. But I am getting some unexpected issues while retrieving data of parsed `JSON`. So let me explain my problem.

I have to parse following `JSON` data using xcode. This is what data to be parsed looks like while I hit same URL in browser:

```
{
"RESPONSE":[
    {"id":"20",
    "username":"john",
    "email":"abc@gmail.com",
    "phone":"1234567890",
    "location":"31.000,71.000"}],
"STATUS":"OK",
"MESSAGE":"Here will be message"
}
```

My code to reach up to this `JSON` data is as follow:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:finalurl];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

If I print object `json` using `NSLog`, i.e. `NSLog(@"json: %@", [json description]);` it looks like:

```
json: {
    MESSAGE = "Here will be message";
    RESPONSE =(
                {
            email = "abc@gmail.com";
            id = 20;
            location = "31.000,71.000";
            phone = 1234567890;
            username = john;
        }
    );
    STATUS = OK;
}
```

So, here I observed two things:

1. Sequence of keys (or nodes) (`MESSAGE`, `RESPONSE` and `STATUS`) is changed as compared to web response above.
2. The `RESPONSE` is get enclosed in `'(' & ')'` braces.

Now if I separate out values for keys `MESSAGE` & `STATUS` and `NsLog`  them, then they get printed as proper string.

Like `msgStr:Here will be message` &  `Status:OK`

**But** if I separate out value for `RESPONSE` as a dictionary and again separating sub values of that dictionary like `email` and `username`, then **I can't getting those as string**.

Here is the code so far I wrote:

```
NSMutableDictionary *response = [json valueForKey:@"RESPONSE"];
NSString *username = [response valueForKey:@"username"];
NSString *emailId = [response valueForKey:@"email"];
```

If I print `username` and `emailId`, then they are **not getting printed as normal string**, instead it outputs as:

```
username:(
    john
)

email:(
    abc@gmail.com
)
```

So my question is why it's not getting as a normal string? If I tried to use this variables further then they show value enclosed within `'(' & ')'` braces. Is this happening because of `NSJSONSerialization`?

Comment: Formatting is changed because of now it is NSDictionary instead of formatted JSON string. NSDictionary has own format for printing its description

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all in your `JSON` response `dictionary`, under the key '**RESPONSE**' you have a array not a `dictionary` and that array contains `dictionary` object. 
So to extract *username* and *email ID* so as below

```
NSMutableDictionary *response = [[[json valueForKey:@"RESPONSE"] objectAtIndex:0]mutableCopy];
 NSString *username = [response valueForKey:@"username"];
 NSString *emailId = [response valueForKey:@"email"];
```

Comment: `[[json valueForKey:@"RESPONSE"] objectAtIndex:0];` is not mutable unless you request the `mutableCopy` like so: `[[[json valueForKey:@"RESPONSE"] objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy];`

Answer (score 4):

When you see braces like that, it represents an array, not a dictionary. Your JSON also shows that by enclosing the data in brackets ('[' and ']'). So:

```
RESPONSE =(
                {
            email = "abc@gmail.com";
            id = 20;
            location = "31.000,71.000";
            phone = 1234567890;
            username = john;
        }
);
```

RESPONSE is an Array of Dictionaries. To access the data, iterate through the array:

```
for (NSDictionary *responseDictionary in [JSONDictionary objectForKey:@"RESPONSE"]) {
        NSString *name = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"username"];
        .....
}
```

or grab a dictionary at an index:

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [[JSONDictionary objectForKey:@"RESPONSE"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *name = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"username"];
```

Whenever in doubt, log the the class:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[dictionary objectForKey:@"key"] class]);
```

to see what is being returned from the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

> 1)Sequence of keys (or nodes) (MESSAGE, RESPONSE and STATUS) is
>   changed as compared to web response above.

The `NSLog` of `NSDictionary` is based on the sorted keys.

> 2)The RESPONSE is get enclosed in '(' & ')' braces.

```
RESPONSE =(
            {
        email = "abc@gmail.com";
        id = 20;
        location = "31.000,71.000";
        phone = 1234567890;
        username = john;
    }
);
```

The `RESPONSE` is a key and the value is an `NSArray`. The array contains one `NSDictionary` object with keys as email, id, location, phone and username.

**NOTE:** () says array. {} says dictionary.

Comment: hey thanks bro, for clearing my theoretical concept. Hence +1, But suryakant's ans worked for me practically.

Answer (score 2):

`RESPONSE` contains an array not an object.

So try like this:

```
NSMutableArray *response = [json valueForKey:@"RESPONSE"];
NSString *username = [[response objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"username"];
NSString *emailId  = [[response objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"email"];
NSLog(@"User=>[%@] Pwd=>[%@]",username ,emailId );
```

Comment: `[json valueForKey:@"RESPONSE"];` is not mutable unless you request the `mutableCopy` like so: `[[json valueForKey:@"RESPONSE"] mutableCopy];`

Comment: @neilco: I just saw your comment (After 3 years). Can you tell me what is the importance of `mutableCopy` in this context ?

Comment: @midhun: In your answer you specified: `NSMutableArray *response = [json valueForKey:@"RESPONSE"];` but `valueForKey:` only returns immutable objects so `response` is actually an instance of `NSArray`, not `NSMutableArray`. If you want `response` to be mutable, you need to call `mutableCopy` on the return value of `valueForKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

## pragma mark - Checking Reachability and Parsing Datas

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=11.021459,76.916332&radius=2000&types=atm&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyD7c1IID7zDCdcfpC69fC7CUqLjz50mcls"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: 0 error: nil];
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
array = [[jsonData objectForKey:@"results"] mutableCopy];
[jsonTableview reloadData];}
```

## pragma mark- UITableView Delegate

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView          
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return array.count;
  }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    
 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *cellid = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView       
 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];
cell = [[UITableViewCell   
 alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle    
  reuseIdentifier:cellid];

cell.textLabel.text = [[array    
 valueForKeyPath:@"name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[array 
valueForKeyPath:@"vicinity"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSURL *imgUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[[array 
valueForKey:@"icon"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl];
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius =        
 cell.imageView.frame.size.width/2;
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

return cell;
 }
```

#import.h

```
@interface JsonViewController :     
UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *jsonTableview;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *barButton;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSArray *array;
@property NSInteger select;
```

Comment: Answering with codes only is not a good reply. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score -2):

By serializing the data, u get a json object. Json object and dictionary are different a bit.

Instead of using:

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

use:

```
NSDictionary    *json    =   (NSDictionary*) data;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` takes the NSData representation of a JSON string and deserialises it into either NSArray or NSDictionary.

Comment: JSON object and NSDictionary are equivalent. The JSON documentation calls it "object", but the JSON documentation applies to all implementations, not just an iOS one. In iOS, "array"s are stored as NSArray*, "object"s are stored as NSDictionary*, "string"s as NSString*, bool, integer and number as NSNumber*. And casting data, which has type NSData*, to NSDictionary* isn't going to do anything useful.