# JSON Parsing Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

Hello I am new to *iOS* development. I am trying to parse a *JSON* response. Below is the top part of the response:

```js
Table =                     
{
  Rows = {
  results = (
            {
  Cells =    {
      results = (
              {
                Key = Rank;
                Value = "6.251145362854";
                ValueType = "Edm.Double";
                "__metadata" =  {
                                 type = "SP.KeyValue";
                                 };
                                },
              {
                Key = DocId;
                Value = 978473;
                ValueType = "Edm.Int64";
                 "__metadata" =                               
              {
                type = "SP.KeyValue";
              };
              },
              {
              Key = WorkId;
              Value = 978473;
              ValueType = "Edm.Int64";
              "__metadata" =  {
                               type = "SP.KeyValue";
                               };
              },
            {
             Key = Title;
             Value = "Vneea Ready!";
             ValueType = "Edm.String";
             "__metadata" =                                              
             {
                type = "SP.KeyValue";
              };
             },.........................
```

Now I am using

```js
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
NSDictionary *results = jsonObject[@"Table"][@"Rows"][@"results"];
```

So I was able to refine it until here, but then I use

```js
NSDictionary *results = jsonObject[@"Table"][@"Rows"][@"results"][@"Cells"];
```

When I am going further for `Cells` and `results` it is giving me `Empty element Error`,
After referring to this post [JSON parsing using NSJSONSerialization in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399087/json-parsing-using-nsjsonserialization-in-ios), it seems like "(" means an array in the response, but it is not working for me. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: can u give ur URL, I show the full answer for u

Comment: This doesn't look like json. Each result entry has ";" instead of "," and all "=" should be ":"

Comment: Please specify which value you have to get from the dictionary after parsing?

Comment: Title Value i want to get from the Dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`results` is an array, not a dictionary, so you cannot access its contents by name.  Your JSON doesn't look well formed, though, because `Key` should be a string ("Title" not Title).

Each element in the results array is a dictionary, so to get the `Value` that corresponds to `Title` you can use

```
NSArray *results=jsonObject[@"Table"][@"Rows"][@"results"];
NSDictionary *result=[results objectAtIndex:0];   // access the first result

for (NSDictionary *result in results) {
   if ([result[@"Key"] isEqualToString:@"Title"]) {
      NSLog(@"The value of Title is %@",result[@"Value"]);
      break;
   }
}
```