# How to access PHP echo data from Swift app?

Tags: php, json, swift

I have a PHP page which echos some `JSON` like so:

```
echo json_encode("Hello");
```

How can I access this in my swift app? I used a method to get data from the website before, when I `println` the data returned, it just prints all of the HTML code for the website (including tags).

```
    let url = NSURL(string: myLinkUrl)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
        println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)) //Prints HTML code
    }
```

I would like to know how to only print the data that the page echos (in this case 'Hello')

Comment: [Refer to this question for accessing JSON in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234531/php-ios-what-is-best-way-to-encode-json-for-web-service/31284984#31284984)

Comment: This answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399087/json-parsing-using-nsjsonserialization-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are printing just the json data in your php page. There should not be any html tags. The json should be in key-value pairs so that you can access it easily. A sample php file to generate valid json is given below.

```
<?php
 $response['data']="Hello";
 echo json_encode("Hello");
?>
```